# Python scrapy how to find more commands

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to access "crawl" command with scrapy but it raises "unknown command: crawl" error. So I figured out I must go to the scrapy dir and run from there. But still through, when i try this:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scrapy>scrapy crawl my_spider
Scrapy 1.4.0 - no active project

Unknown command: crawl
```

I really have no idea about what must i do. Thanks for your helpfullness <3

**EDIT:**

When I run on my project file, which is i created myself on D dir, still raises the same error. This is my project file:

```
D:\atexit\crawl>ls
source.py  source.pyc  spider.py
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scrapy crawl` should be executed inside your project folder and then only it would work.

The project folder would have a `scrapy.cfg` file. You can execute the command in any subfolder inside the project as well. Scrapy will look for a `scrapy.cfg` in current or parent folders.

Comment: Thanks but when I go to the my project file and enter this code "
D:\atexit\crawl>scrapy crawl my_spider" it still says unknown command. And there is no scrapy.cfg file either, Where is my mistake

Comment: How did you create the project? did you use `scrapy startproject` to create the project?

Comment: Nope, just created a directory myself

Comment: You need to use `scrapy runspider <yourscraperfile>` if you need to use scrapy crawl then you should start the project using `scrapy startproject`